# Matlab or R: replace elements in matrix by values from another matrix in order

Tags: r, matlab

I have a problem to solve in either Matlab or R (preferably in R).

Imagine I have a vector A with 10 elements.

I have also a vector B with 30 elements, of which 10 have value 'x'.

Now, I want to replace all the 'x' in B by the corresponding values taken from A, *in the order that is established in A*. Once a value in A is taken, the next one is ready to be used when the next 'x' in B is found.

Note that the sizes of A and B are different, it's the number of 'x' cells that coincides with the size of A.

I have tried different ways to do it. Any suggestion on how to program this?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the number of `x` entries in `B` matches the length of `A`, this will do what you want:

```
B[B=='x'] <- A
```

(It should be clear that this is the `R` solution.)

Comment: Many thanks! It was so easy, but I got lost in a useless loop. But now, what if A is larger than the number of 'x' in B? Then one would like to replace the 'x' by elements from B, until there are no more 'x' left.

Comment: It'll work as you'd expect but will give a warning if sizes are not multiples of each other. And if A is smaller it will recycle. Just try a few simple examples and see what happens.

Comment: @eddi It will do what *I* expect in those cases, yes.  I'm not so sure about the questioner.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase, it'll work exactly as @user13837 wanted it to work in their question. Better? ;)

Answer (score 2):

#### MATLAB Solution

In MATLAB it's quite simple, use logical indexing:

```
B(B == 'x') = A;
```